# Java Swing MouseListener Calling classes

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

Need a bit of guidance on some homework for college. So if you could give me pointers rather than the actual solution that would be much appreciated.

Been tasked to modify an existing program so that when the mouse hovers over the dark squares of a draughts board, only the dark squares are changed to a different colour. When the mouse exits the dark square, it goes back to its original colour.

I have included the two classes I feel are important to solving this task.

Thankyou for any help received. Been scratching my noggin' on this one for a while now.
Part of the task is to only edit the Board class and no others.

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
private Square square;
private Square[][] squares;
private ArrayList<DraughtsPiece> lightPieces;
private ArrayList<DraughtsPiece> darkPieces;

public Board(int numRows)
{
    super(new GridLayout(numRows, numRows));
    squares = new Square[numRows][numRows];
    lightPieces = new ArrayList<DraughtsPiece>();
    darkPieces = new ArrayList<DraughtsPiece>();

    setupBoard(numRows);
    setupPieces(numRows);

    allocatePieces();
}

private void setupBoard(int numRows)
{

    boolean lightSquare = true;

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < numRows; col++)
        {
            if (lightSquare)
            {
                squares[row][col] = new Square(Square.LIGHT_SQUARE_COLOUR, 
row + 1, col + 1);
            }
            else
            {

                squares[row][col] = new Square(Square.DARK_SQUARE_COLOUR, 
row + 1, col + 1);
                addMouseListener(this);
            }
            add(squares[row][col]);
            lightSquare = !lightSquare;
        }
        lightSquare = !lightSquare;
    }
}

private void setupPieces(int numRows)
{
    int numPieces = ((numRows * numRows) - (2 * numRows)) / 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPieces; i++)
    {
        DraughtsPiece p = new 
  DraughtsPiece(DraughtsPiece.LIGHT_PIECE_COLOUR);
        lightPieces.add(p);

        p = new DraughtsPiece(DraughtsPiece.DARK_PIECE_COLOUR);
        darkPieces.add(p);

    }
}

private void allocatePieces()
{
    int row = squares.length - 1;
    int col = 0;

    for (DraughtsPiece p : lightPieces)
    {
        squares[row][col].setPiece(p);
        col += 2;
        if (col >= squares[0].length)
        {
            col = row % 2;
            row--;
        }
    }

    row = 0;
    col = squares[0].length - 1;
    for (DraughtsPiece p : darkPieces)
    {
        squares[row][col].setPiece(p);
        col -= 2;
        if (col < 0)
        {
            row++;
            col = squares[0].length - 1 - (row % 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand a mouse adapter can be used to remove empty methods for the MouseListener, although we have not yet been taught this.
I haven't included the unused methods in this code.

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
{
if (e.getSource().equals(square))
{
 square.exit();
}
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
{
if (e.getSource().equals(square))
{
 square.enter();
}
}
```

And here is the Square Class

```
public class Square extends JPanel
{
public static final Color LIGHT_SQUARE_COLOUR = new Color(0xdfdfdf);
public static final Color DARK_SQUARE_COLOUR = new Color(0x333333);
public static final Color SELECTED_DARK_SQUARE_COLOUR = Color.YELLOW;

private Color background;
private int row, column;
private Color selectedBackground;
private DraughtsPiece piece;
private boolean selected = false;

public Square(Color c, int row, int col)
{
    super(new BorderLayout());
    background = c;
    this.row = row;
    this.column = col;
    setBackground(background);
    if (background == DARK_SQUARE_COLOUR)
    {
        selectedBackground = SELECTED_DARK_SQUARE_COLOUR;
    }
    piece = null;
 }

 public int getRow()
 {
    return row;
}

public int getColumn()
{
    return column;
}

public void setPiece(DraughtsPiece piece)
{
    if (piece == null && this.piece != null)
    {
        remove(this.piece);
        this.piece.setSquare(null);
        this.piece = null;
    }
    else if (piece != null && this.piece == null)
    {
        this.piece = piece;
        piece.setSquare(this);
        add(piece);
    }
 }

 public DraughtsPiece getPiece()
 {
    return piece;
 }

 protected void enter()
 {
    setBackground(selectedBackground);
 }

 protected void exit()
 {
    setBackground(background);
 }

 protected void setSelected(boolean b)
 {
    selected = b;
    setBackground(b == false ? background : selectedBackground);
 }


 }
```

Comment: have you run/debugged the code? Does it work as you expect?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply.
Code creates a draughts board fine, however when I hover over the dark pieces they do not change to yellow.

I understand I'm probably making some simple errors here so sorry in advance!

Comment: Place a breakpoint and step through the code. That will tell you if the check for dark works

Comment: Thankyou. Went through with a breakpoint, MouseListener does not work correctly. 

New to Java so I don't think I have implemented the e.getSource() correctly. Tried checking online guides but haven't been much help.

Comment: My advice is that learn to use/love debuggers. They will answer the vast majority of your questions faster than posting here or anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always comparing to the same `Square` object (the one called `square`), which is never used.

Youi should use directly the `Square` that is the source of the event, e.g :

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
{
    if (e.getSource() instanceof Square)
    {
         ((Square)e.getSource()).exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thankyou for your answer. 
However the instanceof operator does not seem to work and throws an error.
Have not seen this used before so unsure as to what it does. Thanks again.

Comment: @RiceCrispy : yes sorry there was an extra parenthesis, I just removed it in last edit. `instanceof` is a keyword to check if an `Object` is of a given class. You don't really need it, since you only register the mouse listeners to `Square` objects anyway, so feel free to remove this check.